# changing compiler options in configure.ac file

Tags: makefile, configure, compiler-flags

I am trying to implement a tool which will be able to produce makefiles/configure script for a different compiler , from existing makefiles or configure.ac files. Basically my intention is to generate a makefile for sun cc from an existing makefile which is actually written for gcc. My first approach was to edit the makefile so that CC option is changed from gcc to CC and the compiler flags also  need to be replaced. But it would be greater  if it is possible to implement at the configure.ac file itself.I need to replace the compiler specific option/flags in a configure.ac file.

A dry run of  a makefile gives the compiler options.Is there any way to get it from configure.ac files. 
Does this approach makes sense?